# \bibliography only shows references from the template

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, texmaker

I have the following codes:

**thesis.tex**

```
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib} 

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}  
\bibliography{Bibliography/sample.bib}
```

**Bibliography/sample.bib**

```
@article{Reference1,
    Author = {Alexander Schuller and Benjamin Dietz and Christoph M. Flath and Christof Weinhardt},
    Journal = {IEEE Transactions on Power Systems},
    Month = {September},
    Number = {29},
    Numpages = {9},
    Pages = {2014-2022},
    Title = {Charging Strategies for Battery Electric Vehicles: Economic Benchmark and V2G Potential},
    Volume = {5},
    Year = {2014}}
```

Still, TeXmaker (Mac OS) displays the standard reference list:
[image]

I tried with changing the bib file name, changing the default bibliography.bib file, and tried with creating new folders/links, but nothing worked out. There is also no other file on my drive, that contains these default references (checked by file search).

How can that be?

I would be grateful for any suggestions!

Thank you very much in advance.

Best
Michael

Comment: Have you run LaTeX/BibTeX/LaTeX/LaTeX?